# Running an asp.net 1.1 app under windows server 2008 64bit

Tags: asp.net, windows-server-2008, 64-bit, compatibility, .net-1.1

Are there any issues with running an asp.net 1.1 application under windows server 2008 64-bit web edition?

Answer (score 3):

I have never tried it myself, but I did find the following pages that you might find interesting:

- [This blog](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/06/02/installing-asp-net-1-1-with-iis7-on-vista-and-windows-2008.aspx) has an in depth walk through of configuring ASP.NET 1.1 on Windows Server 2008. The author does not say if it is x86 or x64, so I would just assume its x86. But either way, it looks like the author had to jump through some hoops to get the ISAPI filter setup correctly.
- I also found [this thread](http://forums.iis.net/t/1150289.aspx) on the IIS7 forums where someone discuses having poor performance from ASP.NET 1.1. on x64 Win2k8. So from poor performance I would assume it worked to some extent. Unfortunately towards the end of the thread the author mentions encounter 500 errors, and then the discuss stops :-(

So from what I've read I would guess that its possible, but I would also guess that you would have less hassle if you could find some alternative that didn't involve both II7 and x64.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently been testing our application on 64 bit 2008. Our application is .net framework 3.5 but we had a few problems.

The main issue we had was with 3rd party components such as Aspose words which were not built for 64 bit and caused an error. Unfortunatly you wont know without trying it..

Answer (score 0):

.NET 1.1 is 32 bit only hence the app pool would have to run as 32 bit and use the classic pipeline.  I haven't tried myself and I would do all that I can to not have to install .NET 1.1 on a 2008 server but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

No problem. Just follow intructions on

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/472/how-to-install-aspnet-11-with-iis7-on-vista-and-windows-2008/

The option "CGI Restrictions" (last step) is found on IIS7 admin by clicking on the machine name.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the article at http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/472/how-to-install-aspnet-11-with-iis7-on-vista-and-windows-2008/ is for NON-R2 versions of Windows Server.

As far as I know ASP.NET 1.1 cannot run (or at least,  not run well) on Windows.

There are some band-aid solutions around that various people have posted / blogged but this isn't supported by Microsoft.

Comment: This is completely incorrect. I have multiple IIS7/IIS7.5 servers running ASP.NET 1.1 without problem. Microsoft even supports it to the extent that when you install .NET 1.1, the compatibility wizard tells you to make sure you get certain updates so that it works well.